# Stuck on solving 2 simultaneous equations with variables. [Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem from Serge Lang's *Basic Mathematics* in Chapter 2, question 9a.

> Let $a,b,c,d$ be numbers such that $ad-bc \neq 0$. Solve the following systems of equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$.
> a) \begin{align*}
> ax + by & = 1\\ 
> cx + dy & = 2
> \end{align*}

I'm fine with solving these sorts of equations with numbers in place of $a,b,c,d$ but trying to solve it with just variables has been a problem. I assume that the information "$ad-bc \neq 0$" is some sort of hint, possibly that I'm able to divide by $ad-bc$ at some point but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-system-of-equations/alg-equivalent-systems-of-equations/v/solving-systems-of-equations-by-elimination

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: with matrices, the system is $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{1\\2},\\$ and $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ can be inverted to solve for $\pmatrix{x\\y}$ if its determinant is non-zero

Comment: Note that $a$ , $b$, $c$ and $d$ are **not** variables. Consider them constants, just like numbers. We call them *parameters*. Try solving the system of equations just the same way you solve a system with numbers, and show us what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Multiply the 1st eqn by $c$ and the 2nd eqn by $a$.  Then the two altered eqn's will each have, as their first term, $(ac)x$.  Therefore, by subtracting the 2nd altered eqn from the 1st altered eqn, you will obtain an eqn that has only the single variable $y$.